# jQuery, .click , .animate, etc. in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This code works perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE.

I've seen similar problems all over the web but don't quite understand the solutions, maybe posting the specific code will help me.  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bgimage").slideDown();
    $("#rcapmenu").delay(1000).animate({opacity: ".9", filter: "alpha(opacity=90)", top: "75%", height: "168px"}, "slow");
        $("#menutext").delay(1500).animate({height: "45px"}, "slow");
    $("#LOGIN").delay(2200).animate({height: "44px", left: "0px"}, "slow");
    $("#CLIENT").delay(2500).animate({height: "44px", left: "0px"}, "slow");
    $("#ABOUT").delay(2800).animate({height: "44px", left: "0px"}, "slow");
    $("#MANAGER").delay(3100).animate({height: "44px", left: "0px"}, "slow");
    $("#rcaplogo").delay(2100).animate({opacity: "1", filter: "alpha(opacity=100)"}, "slow");       $(".slidingDiv").hide();

$('#MANAGER').bind('click', function(){

$(".slidingDiv").animate({height: "0px", top: "455px"}, "slow").delay(1000).animate({height: "450px", top: "0px"}, "slow");
getdata('text.php','slidingDiv');
});

$('#ABOUT').click(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").animate({height: "0px", top: "455px"}, "slow").delay(1000).animate({height: "450px", top: "0px"}, "slow");
getdata('text.php','slidingDiv');
});

$('#CLIENT').click(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").animate({height: "0px", top: "455px"}, "slow").delay(1000).animate({height: "450px", top: "0px"}, "slow");
getdata('text.php','slidingDiv');
});

$('#LOGIN').click(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").animate({height: "0px", top: "455px"}, "slow").delay(1000).animate({height: "450px", top: "0px"}, "slow");
getdata('text.php','slidingDiv');
});

$('.right').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").animate({height: "0px", top: "455px"}, "slow");
}); 
});
</script>
```

When I click the divs with the corresponding IDs nothing happens in IE, but in Chrome the effect I'm looking for happens perfectly.  I tried both .bind('click', function() ..... and just .click as you can see.

Comment: What do you get in the developer tools? Press F-12 at your page, refresh is needed, and check the console output.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used `bind()` on `#MANAGER` but `click()` on everything else?  I have no idea if it makes a difference to your problem but consistency in the code always makes troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting the effect in a new JQuery function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.EFFECT NAME = YOUR EFFECT
```

So you can just do this:

```
$('#id').EFFECT NAME();
```

Sorry I couldn't help anymore but this might improve the code a little.